# Dask delayed / dask array no response

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I have a distributed dask cluster setup and I have used it to load and transform a bunch of data. Works like a charm.

I'm want to use it do some processing in parallel. Here's my function

```
el = 5000
n_using = 26
n_across= 6

mat = np.random.random((el,n_using,n_across))
idx = np.tril_indices(n_across*2, -n_across)

def get_vals(c1, m, el, idx):
    m1 = m[c1,:,:]
    corr_vals = np.zeros((el, (n_across//2)*(n_across+1)))
    for c2 in range(c1+1, el):
        corr = np.corrcoef(m1.T, m[c2,:,:].T)
        corr_vals[c2] = corr[idx]
        
    return corr_vals

lazy_get_val = dask.delayed(get_vals, pure=True)
```

Here is a single processor version of what I'm trying to do:

```
arrays = [get_vals(c1, mat, el, idx) for c1 in range(el)]
all_corr = np.stack(arrays, axis=0)
```

Works fine but takes a few hours.
Here's my go at doing this in dask:

```
lazy_list = [lazy_get_val(c1, mat, el, idx) for c1 in range(el)]
arrays = [da.from_delayed(lazy_item, dtype=float, shape=(el, 21)) for lazy_item in lazy_list]
all_corr = da.stack(arrays, axis=0)
```

Even if it run `all_corr[1].compute()`, it just sits there and doesn't respond. When I interrupt the kernel, it seems to be stuck at /distributed/utils.py:

> ~/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py in sync(loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
>
> ```
>     249     else:
>     250         while not e.is_set():
> --> 251             e.wait(10)
>     252     if error[0]:
>     253         six.reraise(*error[0])
> ```

Any suggestions on debugging this?

---

Other things:

- If I run it with a smaller `mat` (el=1000) and it runs fine.
- If I make `el = 5000`, it hangs.
- If I interrupt the kernel and run it again with `el = 1000`, it hangs.

Comment: Can I ask you for an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this?  You're close, but I don't know what mat is supposed to be here.  Ideally something simple that a potenial question asker could copy-paste to reproduce your issue would be ideal.

Comment: Sorry. I have updated it. Thanks again for looking into it.

Comment: @MRocklin - Any ideas on this? I switched to using joblib and it works just fine but I'd rather use dask since I have a pretty sweet cluster all set up.

Answer (score 2):

After adding imports to the example I ran things and it was very slow while building the graph.  This can be improved by avoiding placing numpy arrays directly in delayed calls as follows:

```
# mat = np.random.random((el,n_using,n_across))
# idx = np.tril_indices(n_across*2, -n_across)
mat = dask.delayed(np.random.random)((el,n_using,n_across))
idx = dask.delayed(np.tril_indices)(n_across*2, -n_across)
```

Or by removing the `pure=True` keyword to dask.delayed (when you set pure=True it has to hash the contents of all inputs to get a unique key for them, you're doing this 5000 times).  I found this out by profiling your code with the `%snakeviz` magic in IPython.

I then ran `all_corr[1].compute()` and it was fine.  I then ran `all_corr.compute()` and it seemed like it would progress to completion, but wasn't very fast.  I suspect that either your tasks are too small so that there is too much overhead, or that your code is spending too much time in Python for loops and so is running into GIL issues.  Not sure which.

The next thing I would recommend trying would be using the dask.distributed scheduler, which would handle the GIL issue better and exacerbate the overhead issue.  Seeing how that performed would probably help isolate the issue.

Comment: Hi Matt - Thanks for your help. Making `mat` and `idx` from delayed random call does solve them problem but not for my 'real' problem. I generated `mat` and `idx` as random matrices to create a mcve, but they come from another source for me. I tried it in dask scheduler and it seems to run fine thought it takes 20mins (vs. 4mins using joblib.Parallel). The tasks might just be too small - i'll stick to joblib. Thanks again for your help.